# If statements JavaScript, maths will not work in my else statement what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

This question is pretty straightforward. I am making a number guessing game and I am now adding an *attempts* function to my game. Every failed attempt should add 1 to my `attempts` variable:

```js
var numberwang = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var attempts = 0;

console.log(numberwang);
console.log(attempts);

document.getElementById("guessbutton").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (document.getElementById("guess").value == numberwang) {

    alert("That's numberwang!");
    attempts = 0;
    console.log("Attempts:",attempts)
  } else {

    alert("That's not numberwang, try again");
    attempts = attempts + 1;
    console.log("Attempts:",attempts)
  }

}
```

```html
<p>Guess a number</p>
<form><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="guessbutton">Guess</button></form>
```

However the else statement argument doesn't work. Each attempt does not add anything to my attempts variable. Can anyone see what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Note: the *else* statement is not working for anything mathematical.

Comment: When creating a variable, like `attempts`, use a declarative statement like `var`. When *updating an existing variable*m do **not** use `var`. The reason for this is that by adding a declaration state like `var`, you're *creating a new variable local to the lexical scope in which it's declared*, not modifying the existing one.

Comment: Sorry that is what I have. Does not work either way.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you please edit your question to include your exact code then? The issue you describe aligns perfectly with the mistake I mentioned above.

Comment: Your example works fine. I see no issues.

Comment: With your latest edit, the code works fine. `console.log(attempts)` after `attempts = attempts + 1` and you will see it is now increasing by `1` each time.

Comment: done. however I dont think the var part changes the output by much. it works either way outside of the statements

Comment: @JohnSonnino If you set a variable that isn't already accessible in the current scope (that is, no `var` or `let` or `const`), it will be declared globally. This means it can be accessed anywhere.

Comment: Guys this does not solve the problem

Comment: Tyler Roper can you run the code yourself and make sure? I do not see this problem solved on my end...

Comment: please, run the snippet of your own code on your question, and do a wrong try

Comment: @JohnSonnino I have run the code and it works as described. There is either a misunderstanding of what's expected here or... something else...? I find it very hard to believe that you aren't seeing the results you expect, assuming I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: I guess I just need to refresh the console.log(attempts) as this doesnt appear to update itself.

Comment: I guess that you think that `console.log()` keeps loggin the value forever after a single call and when the value changes it also logs. But it's not like that... every call to console.log() is unique for that moment showing the value or the text on that exact moment that `.log()` is called, so if you want to see if some variable changed value, you need to call `.log()` again...

Comment: how can I add a console.log(attempts) function after the if statement? I keep getting NaN

Comment: Did you ran the code snippet of your own question? The code in it is working perfectly... no `NaN`, with `console.log()` loggin the values correctly. You are the only one here that says it's not working, everybody else is seeing the code working flawlessly... please, clarify your question, because nobody is able to reproduce the error right now

Comment: My mistake this is working. Please see above question on console.log(attempts). I have put this before the last curley bracket but it gives Nan.

Comment: Nevermind I will just put it in each if statement. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you use the `var` keyword, you are making a new variable. You should remove the `var` inside both the if and the else. This will let you change the outer `attempts` variable, and not the new one that you define by using the `var`.

```js
var numberwang = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var attempts = 0;
document.getElementById("guessbutton").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (document.getElementById("guess").value == numberwang) {

    alert("That's numberwang!");
    attempts = 0;

  } else {

    alert("That's not numberwang, try again");
    attempts = attempts + 1;
    

  }
  console.log("Attempts is: "+attempts);

}
```

```html
<p>Guess a number</p>
<form><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="guessbutton">Guess</button></form>
```

I think that I understand what you are having a problem with. You expect what is already logged to the console to change when the variable changes. That's not how `console.log` works. It only logs the **current** value of the variable. If you want to see the new value, you should log it again, in this case after each guess is made.

Comment: @JohnSonnino If you log the `attempts` after each guess, you will see that it is indeed increasing every time now.

Comment: @JohnSonnino I think that I understand what you are having a problem with. You expect what is already logged to the console to change when the variable changes. That's not how `console.log` works. It only logs the **current** value of the variable. If you want to see the new value, you should log it again, in this case after each guess is made.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a variable everytime you click.
Removing the "var" from inside the if/else block

```js
<p>Guess a number</p>

<form><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="guessbutton">Guess</button></form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var numberwang = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var attempts = 0;

    console.log(numberwang);
    console.log(attempts);

    document.getElementById("guessbutton").onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (document.getElementById("guess").value == numberwang) {

            alert("That's numberwang!");
            attempts = 0;

        } else {

            alert("That's not numberwang, try again");
            attempts = attempts + 1;

        }

    }

</script>
```